# Angular Unit Testing - How to test a service which creates a Websocket

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I need to write a unit test for the following code:

```js
getSomething(id: string): Observable<State | null> {
  return new WebSocketSubject(webSocket(`ws://<websocket>`)
    .pipe(
      catchError(err => {
        console.error('Error in WebSocket connection: ', err);
        return concat(
          of(null),
          throwError(err)
        );
      }),
      retryWhen(errors =>
        errors.pipe(
          delay(1000)
        )
      )
    )
  );
}
```

I would like to write two tests to:

- check if the websocket is created;
- generate the error in websocket connection to achieve a good coverage.

I wrote first test as below but I don't know what to expect here:

```js
it('should get Something create websocket', () => {
  service.getSomething('test').subscribe(
    data => expect(data).toBeInstanceOf(webSocket),
      fail
  ); 
});
```

Your inputs are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: Unit test means you want to check how your code is working. But "to check if the websocket is created" means to check if runtime (presumably browser, but could be NodeJS during tests) supports websockets, and it is actually created, and it connects to external service, etc. -- this is functional/integration test, and probably not what you want to do within your unit tests. That being said, you could abstract away websocket creation by injecting some custom factory which is overridden in your tests with a simple subject while still using `WebSocketSubject` when app is running.

Comment: I got it, could you point to me some examples that will help me. Thank you for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to provide an example as a comment, so, here goes full answer.

This is what I was talking about:

```js
@Injectable()
class WebSocketFactory {
  createWebSocket<T>(url: string): WebSocketSubject<T> {
    return webSocket(url);
  }
}

class SomeClass {
  constructor(private readonly factory: WebSocketFactory) {
  }

  getSomething(id: string): Observable<State | null> {
    return this.factory.createWebSocket(`ws://<websocket>`).pipe(
      catchError((err) => {
        console.error("Error in WebSocket connection: ", err);
        return concat(of(null), throwError(err));
      }),
      retryWhen((errors) => errors.pipe(delay(1000)))
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see, I have abstracted websocket creation into a tiny service `WebSocketFactory`, and this gives us the following benefit (note: this is not a ready-to-reuse code, please read below):

```js
describe('SomeClass', () => {
  let subject = new Subject<any>();
  let service: SomeClass;

  beforeEach(() => {
    service = new SomeClass({
      createWebSocket: <T>() => subject as WebSocketSubject<T>,
    });
  });

  it('should do something useful', () => {
    subject.next(/* something */);
    service.getSomething('test').subscribe(
      data => expect(data).toBeEqual(/* something */),
        fail
    ); 
  });  
});
```

As you can see, now you're in full control of when and how the makeshift websocket created, you have access to internals, you can send any value, close it early, etc. -- just use `subject` for that, not a real `WebSocket` object.

Now, some notes, caveats, and pointers.

1. The test code above does not work, it just illustrates the point. To make it work, you need to actually set up observable testing, which is rather untrivial due to asynchronous nature of observables. That's a huge topic, I'd start with some article like [this](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/how-to-test-observables-a00038c7faad) and [this](https://rxjs.dev/guide/testing/marble-testing).
2. I'm using a makeshift mock thingie (object literal that implements WebSocketFactory by wrapping `subject`), but there are things that make this easier and more powerful: [spies](https://scriptverse.academy/tutorials/jasmine-spyon.html). But that's a big topic on its own.
3. The example above is simple, but if your code is much more complex, you might want to use `TestBed` ([docs](https://angular.io/guide/testing-services#angular-testbed)) class provided by Angular and do provider override instead of manually creating instances.
4. Apparently `webSocket` returns `WebSocketSubject` ([docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/webSocket/webSocket)), so, I have adjusted the code accordingly.
5. Instead of providing full class as a factory, you could get away with just a function (something like `constructor(private readonly webSocket: typeof webSocket) {}`, or even `constructor(@Optional() private readonly webSocket: typeof webSocket = webSocket) {}`), I just generally prefer to wrap things in classes for easier extension if some future tasks call for it.
6. I know this is not a full answer as it does not directly address your "I don't know what to expect here" -- that's because you've hit rather complex set of topics mixed together: [dependency inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) -- simplification via abstraction of websocket creation, rxjx/observable testing (or even testing of asynchronous operations in general), unit vs. functional/integrational testing. Each of these topics is rather huge, but I hope all the links above will get you started.

Comment: Thank you alx for your help. I will take a look at the links you provided.